# language types (IBM DB2) setting with db2cmd.exe in Emacs SQL mode

Tags: emacs, db2, codepages

Sure this is not really problem of Emacs SQL mode. But I think, somebody can help me to find solution.

I use SQL mode through db2cmd.exe in Emacs, I got below information:

**SQL0863W A successful connection was made, but only single byte characters should be used. SQLSTATE=01539**

Here is a solution, if I change Windows environment.
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0209kline/0209kline.html

**But I can’t change anything in my Windows 7.** I use Emacs every day and Emacs has very good language/coding system, so Emacs can delete this problem with correct setting.

DB2 Host Code: 1141 Germany Euro

I tried many times, but no more idea. Did somebody already have a solution?

Comment: I don't think emacs can do anything about it. I wish it could - but it is totally out of its control. db2cmd uses Windows API for encoding/conversion, and these will work only with languages installed on your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to fix this by setting the `DB2CODEPAGE` environment variable in your `.emacs` file to the appropriate codepage:

```
;; Set DB2CODEPAGE environment DB2 Command Line Processor (CLP)
;; (DB2 CLP is called by 'sql-db2)
(setenv "DB2CODEPAGE" "1252")
```

Codepage 1252 is *Windows West European Latin*; 1208 is *UTF-8*.

Obviously (perhaps) you'd need to restart Emacs to pick this change up.

Comment: wow, thanks. But i think i need a license for connection with db2cmd.exe: 
SQL1598N An attempt to connect to the database server failed because of a licensing prolem. SQLSTATE=42968.
Why other client with JDBC don't need a license? :(

Comment: Sounds like you're connecting to a mainframe?  If so you need a DB2 Connect license to use the CLP.  Java needs this license, too – that's why apps connecting to DB2 on z/OS need both the `db2jcc.jar` file *and* the `db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar` file in `CLASSPATH`.

Comment: I asked my colleague, we don't have the license for CLP. :-(